# What is the worst-case time complexity for inserting a node into a binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, binary-tree

What is the worst-case time complexity for inserting a node into a binary search tree?

Comment: What do you think? O(n) in case you must traverse through the whole tree.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a "pure" binary search tree that doesn't do any balancing, then the worst-case runtime for inserting an element is Θ(n). This happens if you have a degenerate binary search tree (one where each node has exactly one child) and the element you end up inserting ends up as a child of the deepest node. For example, if you try building a BST by inserting the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., n in a way where at each step you insert either the smallest or the largest of the remaining numbers, you'll trigger this case.

If you are using a self-balancing binary search tree, such as an AVL tree or a red/black tree, the worst-case runtime is Θ(log n) because these trees guarantee that the height of the tree never exceeds Θ(log n) and the runtime of an insertion is proportional, in the worst-case, to the height of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

`O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes. That happens, for example, if you insert all the keys in a ordered way

Comment: Yes, the binary tree does no better than a singly linked list in that case.

Comment: There are self-balancing binary trees, e.g. [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree).

Comment: yes @user3386109, but in the absence of clarification one assumes that there is no balancing strategy.

Comment: In the absence of clarification, you should ask for clarification, or give a comprehensive answer as templatetypedef did.

Comment: I think it's debatable @user3386109. Much literature uses the adjective "balanced" in order to do the distinction.